# How to prevent logging out automatically when the back button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using code to logout of application automatically when the browser is closed, but the impact of the code is when I press the browser's back button and navigate to another page then also it automatically logout from the application.

I want my code to logout automatically only when the browser is closed and not when I am navigating through back button

can you help me in this, Thanks

Here is my code

```
$(window).on('mouseover', (function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}));

$(window).on('mouseout', (function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
}));

function ConfirmLeave() {
    $.get("call to a php code to logout");
}

var prevKey="";
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.key=="F5"){
        window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
    }else if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "W" && prevKey == "CONTROL") {
        window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
    }else if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "R" && prevKey == "CONTROL") {
        window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
    }else if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "F4" && prevKey == "ALT") {
        window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
    }
    prevKey = e.key.toUpperCase();
});
```

The php code is

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this->load->driver('cache');
$this->cache->clean();
ob_clean();
redirect("login page");
```

Answer (score 0):

onbeforeunload event occurs when we close the browser and also when we press the back button. It fails to distinguish between the 2 actions.

Comment: Is it possible for adding exception for back button and solve this issue?

Comment: There is no direct method as such but in html5 you can use history API. oppopstate event will be fired when user goes back to previously visited page.